# iPhone attempts to mount network share when connected to Mac

Tags: macos, mount, iphone, ios

On the rare occasions that I plug my iPhone 12 into my iMac via USB, I'll get a message popping up in Finder to the effect of `There was a problem connecting to the server "nas.local"`, nas.local being the hostname of a NAS that I got rid of years ago. I am entirely baffled as to why the system is attempting to mount a network volume when I plug in my iPhone. This is more of a paper cut than anything else; I'm just curious as to what's happening. I did try monitoring Console when plugging in the iPhone, and I found a message being emitted by process NetAuthSysAgent with the URL of the SMB share that it's attempting to mount, but that's where my troubleshooting has come to an end; my DuckDuckGo-fu is too weak for this one.

Comment: I think if I were you I might go through the apps on my iPhone looking for anything I may have used with the NAS, and delete it (or reset its preferences). SMB apps, file sharing apps, home media streaming apps like Plex, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked the "Automatically sync when this phone is connected" option, and now the message no longer appears. I'd noticed that when the message came up, it was attempting to sync, and was on step 3 of 4 - determining tracks to sync. Perhaps once upon a time, I had my iTunes library on the network share, so it was attempting to sync from that? Now that I'm using iCloud Music library, I no longer even see those options, and I have no need to sync, so this is a decent resolution, I guess.